# Padding on left side of page

Tags: html, css

Hi I am getting a padding for a random reason its on the left side of the page loader.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5zf7p9n/
jsfiddle
`<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/b5zf7p9n/"></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body has a margin of 8px for some reason.

Set:

```
body { margin:0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Dude! I appreciate it.

Comment: Will Do Sir! I was just waiting for timer

Answer (score 0):

if you change your #object to margin-left:0px; rather than  margin-left:auto; there is no more space on the left.

Answer (score 0):

that is because, when you create a `.html` page it automatically added `margin` and `padding`. so when you create a page what you should do is always add style to the bodh like this.

if you use internal style, add this code between `title` end tag and `head` end tag,

```
<style>
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
</style>
```

else if you use external style, just add

```
 body{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
```